# Multiple APScheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am trying to create an Job scheduler feature and came across APScheduler. I have few doubts that I've listed down which I couldn't gather much infos.

- I heard that with multiple schedulers running(Assume 3 schedulers are running), if we add a job(Job A) using a particular scheduler(scheduler 1) this particular scheduler is responsible for the job execution. Scheduler 2 won't be taking Job A. Is that true?
- Incase if I am using multiple scheduler with a single job store say mongodb, will there be any duplication in the job execution?
- Do the APScheduler have failover mechanism incase a scheduler went down and can we make the other schedulers to take the jobs of scheduler that went down.
- And I am thinking of using Celery for the job execution. Basically the job trigger a function which in-turn calls the celery worker. Is this an effective way to execute the jobs? Will there be any limitation/blocking with APScheduler?

Tried going through multiple blogs and docs. Have tried the celery part, just wanted to know if the way i'm going is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and the FAQ yet? Those should answer some of your questions.